# How do you print the top most used clients IP with a certain status code.?

Tags: python, regex, printing, conditional-statements, text-files

```
import os
import re 
from collections import Counter 
from collections import OrderedDict 
fileNames = []
textInfo = []
d = {}

currentDirectoryPath = os.getcwd()
print(currentDirectoryPath)


regexp = re.compile(
    r'(?P<clientIP>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).+\['
    + '(?P<timestamp>\d{2}/[A-Z][a-z]{2}/\d\d\d\d).+\"'
    + '(?P<action>[A-Z]{3,4}).+\"'  
    + '\s*(?P<statuscode>[1-5][0-9][0-9])'
    )



os.chdir("/content/drive/log")
currentDirectoryPath = os.getcwd()
listOfFileNames = os.listdir(currentDirectoryPath)
#for files in listOfFileNames :
    #print(files) 


f = open('access_1.log', 'r')
matched = 0
failed = 0
cnt_clientIPs = Counter()
cnt_clientAction = Counter()
cnt_clientTimeStamp = Counter()
cnt_clientStatusCode = Counter()


for line in f:
    m = re.match(regexp, line)
    if m:
        cnt_clientIPs.update([m.group('clientIP')])
        cnt_clientAction.update([m.group('action')])
        cnt_clientStatusCode.update([m.group('statuscode')])
        matched += 1
    else:
        failed += 1
        continue

    print("""""\
client .........: %s
timestamp ......: %s
action .........: %s
statuscode.........: %s
""" % ( m.group('clientIP'),
        m.group('timestamp'),
        m.group('action'),
        m.group('statuscode'),
    ))

for line in f:
    m = re.match(regexp, line)
    if m:
      d = {m.group("clientIP"): m.group("statuscode")}

print(d)


userInputIP = input("Enter how many of the top clients you want to see. ")
print('[*] %d lines matched the regular expression' % (matched))
print('[*] %d lines failed to match the regular expression' % (failed), end='\n\n')
print('[*] ============================================')
print('[*] '+ userInputIP +' Most Frequently Occurring Clients Queried')
print('[*] ============================================')

for clientIP, count in cnt_clientIPs.most_common(int(userInputIP)):
    print('[*] %30s: %d' % (clientIP, count))
print('[*] ============================================')


userInputAction = input("Enter how many of the top actions you want to see. ")
print('[*] '+ userInputAction +' Most Frequently Occurring Clients Actions')
print('[*] ============================================')

for action, count in cnt_clientAction.most_common(int(userInputAction)):
    print('[*] %30s: %d' % (action, count))
print('[*] ============================================')


userInputIpPlusStatus = input("Enter how many of the top clients  you want to see. and there status code ")
print('[*] '+ userInputIpPlusStatus +' Most Frequently Occurring Clients IP and Status Code')
print('[*] ============================================')


for clientIP,  count in cnt_clientIPs.most_common(int(userInputIpPlusStatus)):
    if (stuatuscode == userStatuscodeInput):
       print('[*] %30s: %d: %5s:' % (clientIP, count,  m.group('statuscode')))
print('[*] ============================================')

Enter how many of the top clients you want to see.5
[*] 49997 lines matched the regular expression
[*] 3 lines failed to match the regular expression

[*] ============================================
[*] 5 Most Frequently Occurring Clients Queried
[*] ============================================
[*]                 205.167.170.15: 15695
[*]                  79.142.95.122: 3207
[*]                  52.22.118.215: 734
[*]                  84.112.161.41: 712
[*]                   37.1.206.196: 371
[*] ============================================
Enter how many of the top actions you want to see.5
[*] 5 Most Frequently Occurring Clients Actions
[*] ============================================
[*]                            GET: 44048
[*]                           POST: 5921
[*]                           HEAD: 25
[*]                            PUT: 3
[*] ============================================

{}
```

I want to print out the Top 5 client IPs with status code 404. Or any status code is given from the user. Here Is some test line below to help. Can that also be done within a certain timeframe? For example to print the Top clients IP with a status code of 404 from January to February?

```
for clientIP,  count in cnt_clientIPs.most_common(int(userInputIpPlusStatus)):
    if (stuatuscode == userStatuscodeInput):
       print('[*] %30s: %d: %5s:' % (clientIP, count,  m.group('statuscode')))
print('[*] ============================================')
```

This part right here is where I am talking about. Trying to add the condition here.

```
80.110.186.51 - - [21/Dec/2015:17:20:12 +0100] "GET /images/stories/raith/oststeiermark.png HTTP/1.1" 200 65225 "http://www.almhuette-raith.at/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1" "-"
80.110.186.51 - - [21/Dec/2015:17:20:12 +0100] "GET /images/stories/raith/garage.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 57339 "http://www.almhuette-raith.at/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1" "-"
80.110.186.51 - - [21/Dec/2015:17:20:12 +0100] "GET /images/stories/slideshow/almhuette_raith_03.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 87782 "http://www.almhuette-raith.at/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1" "-"
80.110.186.51 - - [21/Dec/2015:17:20:12 +0100] "GET /images/stories/raith/steiermark_herz.png HTTP/1.1" 200 39683 "http://www.almhuette-raith.at/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1" "-"
```

These lines above are some test lines to help you guys out and to show what I am dealing with in the text files.

Comment: If you use `+` on strings (not recommended) you have to repeat the `r` every time.

Comment: @KlausD. that doesn't seem to be the problem in this program.

Comment: @tdelaney hey again. I need some help on this one. I've been struggling on getting the status code to be one of the qualifiers to print the new IP addresses. For an example, I would like to get the top IP addresses for a status code of 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cnt_clientStatusCode` counter should be counting tuples consisting of ip/status code pairs:

```
for line in f:
    m = re.match(regexp, line)
    if m:
        client_ip = m.group('clientIP')
        statuscode = m.group('statuscode')
        client_statuscode = (client_ip, statuscode) # ip / status code combination
        cnt_clientIPs.update([client_ip])
        cnt_clientAction.update([m.group('action')])
        cnt_clientStatusCode.update([client_statuscode])
        matched += 1
    else:
        failed += 1
        continue
```

Then you can list the `n` most frequent combinations where `n = int(userInputIpPlusStatus)` thus:

```
for (clientIP, statusCode),  count in cnt_clientStatusCode.most_common(int(userInputIpPlusStatus)):
    print('[*] %30s: %d: %5s:' % (clientIP, count, statusCode))
print('[*] ============================================')
```

You can, of course, put out an additional question asking what specific status code the user is interested in and only print items with that particular status code. The logic for that is:

```
wanted_status_code = input("What status code are you interested in: ")
userInputIpPlusStatus = input("Enter how many of the top clients do you want to see for this status code: ")

n = int(userInputIpPlusStatus)
count = 0
for (clientIP, statusCode),  count in cnt_clientStatusCode.most_common():
    if statusCode == wanted_status_code:
        print('[*] %30s: %d: %5s:' % (clientIP, count, statusCode))
        count += 1
        if count == n:
            break
print('[*] ============================================')
```

**Update**

If you want to make the search for a particular status code more efficient, then have a dictionary of counters whose keys are the status codes and whose values are Counters of client ips:

```
from collections import defaultdict
status_dict = defaultdict(Counter)

for line in f.split:
    m = re.match(regexp, line)
    if m:
        client_ip = m.group('clientIP')
        statuscode = m.group('statuscode')
        client_statuscode = (client_ip, statuscode)
        cnt_clientIPs.update([client_ip])
        cnt_clientAction.update([m.group('action')])
        cnt_clientStatusCode.update([client_statuscode])
        status_dict[statuscode].update([client_ip])
        matched += 1
    else:
        failed += 1
        continue
```

Then:

```
wanted_status_code = input("What status code are you interested in: ")
userInputIpPlusStatus = input("Enter how many of the top clients do you want to see for this status code: ")

for clientIP,  count in status_dict.get(wanted_status_code, Counter()).most_common(int(userInputIpPlusStatus)):
    print('[*] %30s: %d: %5s:' % (clientIP, count, wanted_status_code))
print('[*] ============================================')
```